# Difference between updatehandler commit and dataimporthandler commit in solr

Tags: solr, commit, dataimporthandler

I was trying to debug some code in Solr, and just got curious to understand the difference between two:

`UpdateRequestHandler extends ContentStreamHandlerBase extends RequestHandlerBase`,

and hence `UpdateRequestHandler` use `RequestHandlerBase.handleCommit` when `commit=true`.

But I could not figure which method does `DataImportHandler` call when `commit=true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataImportHandler` performs the commit at [line 308 - 313 (for 4.8.1 at least) in `org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DocBuilder.java/#308). This calls, depending on the implementation, [commit on `org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DocBuilder.java#309), which in turn [creates an instance of `org.apache.solr.update.CommitUpdateCommand`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/SolrWriter.java#107) that's sent into [`org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/SolrWriter.java#108).

So the flow is:

```
DataImportHandler
  DocBuilder
    SolrWriter
      CommitUpdateCommand
      UpdateRequestProcessor
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that even after `CommitUpdateCommand` is being called, still "delete" messages don't get committed to disc.
Because as per my debugging all these methods are being called, but I cannot see indexing messages on disc for delete messages, but it works fine for add messages.